# GWT MVP with a table

Tags: gwt, mvp

When working with MVP in GWT how would you work with a table?  For example if you had a table of users does your view look like this?

```
public interface MyDisplay{

HasValue<User> users();

}
```

or would it be more like this?

```
public interface MyDisplay{

HasValue<TableRow> rows();

}
```

MVP makes a ton of sense until you start dealing with widgets that need to display lists of non-primitive data.  Can anybody shed some light?

This mailing list archive appears to ask the same question but never reaches a solid resolution...

http://www.mail-archive.com/google-web-toolkit@googlegroups.com/msg24546.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HasValue<User>` or `HasValue<TableRow>` would not work in this case, because this would only permit handling a single row.
You could maybe use a `HasValue<List<User>>` but that would mean, that your view has to render the entire table on each change.

I might be wrong, but I think for tables its best to use a [Supervising Presenter](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html) instead of the [Passive View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html). 
Have a look at the [PagingScrollTable](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/PagingScrollTable) widget in the [GWT Incubator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/):

```
public class PagingScrollTable<RowType> extends AbstractScrollTable implements
    HasTableDefinition<RowType>, ... {
  ...
  TableModel<RowType> getTableModel() 
  ...
}
```

For a `PagingScrollTable`, a [`MutableTableModel<RowType>`](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/javadoc/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/client/MutableTableModel.html) is used as implementation of [`TableModel<RowType>`](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/javadoc/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/client/TableModel.html).

`MutableTableModel<RowType>` in turn implements the following interfaces:

[`HasRowCountChangeHandlers`](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/javadoc/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/event/client/HasRowCountChangeHandlers.html), [`HasRowInsertionHandlers`](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/javadoc/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/event/client/HasRowInsertionHandlers.html), [`HasRowRemovalHandlers`](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/javadoc/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/event/client/HasRowRemovalHandlers.html), [`HasRowValueChangeHandlers<RowType>`](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/javadoc/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/event/client/HasRowValueChangeHandlers.html)

The `PagingScrollTable` [registers itself as listener on the `MutableTableModel`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/client/PagingScrollTable.java#450) and therefore gets very fine-grained notifications of updates. The resulting implementation should be very performant.

Comment: It is possible to have a table using a passive view but you essentially need to redraw the entire table every time you want to add/remove a row or sort anything.  This is because the display interface would have a method such as setRows(List<List<Widget>>widgets) where the entire table gets set and the view simply lays out many many widgets in a grid (one List<Widget> per row where each Widget is a column).

In terms of performance I am not sure how slow it would really be as I have not tested with large amounts of data yet.  I assume using a table model would be faster (if speed is an issue).

Answer (score 2):

this discussion does reach a resolution for similar question:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/4887a7565d05f349?tvc=2

Answer (score 2):

This might be a very interesting blog post:

http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2010/03/31/gwt-mvp-tables.html